# CreateResponse method in asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

calling this method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product item)
{
    item = repository.Add(item);
    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse<Product>CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

    string uri = Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

Is causing a compile-time error:

```
'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and the
            best extension method overload 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<T>
(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Net.HttpStatusCode, T)' has some invalid arguments.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please include the class definition as well, for example, `public ProductsController : ApiController {`

Comment: OK. I think I got it. The class definition is: `public class ProductsController : Controller`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The runtime type of `item` is probably not an instance of `Product`. You should be able to do this:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
```

Even if `item` was an instance of `Product`, the generic `<Product>` argument is redundant and not necessary. If you used ReSharper, it would tell you that the "(Generic) Type argument specification is redundant".

**Update**

Does your class extend from `Controller` or `ApiController`? The error should be `'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for...`, not `'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for...`.

WebApi controllers should extend from `ApiController`, not `Controller`. In an MVC controller, `this.Request` points to an instance of `System.Web.HttpRequestBase`. In a WebAPI controller, `this.Request` points to an instance of `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`.

Comment: whats for .net core?

Answer (score 19):

CreateResponse is an extension method defined in `System.Net.Http` namespace. 
Make sure to add a reference to `System.Net.Http` and `System.Net.Http.Formatting` in your project and add a correct using directive:

**C#:**
`using System.Net.Http;`

**VB:**
`Import System.Net.Http`