# System.Web.HttpRequestBase does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http

I'm getting this error on this method:

```
        [HttpGet]            
        public HttpResponseMessage Search([ModelBinder(typeof(ApiDataTablesModelBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
        {
            var sortedColumn = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns().SingleOrDefault();

            bool isDesc = false;
            string sortField = "ID";

            // get all projects and order them
            var projects = lkp_surveyRepo.GetAll();//.OrderBy(sortField, isDesc).ToList();

            // filtered projects
            var filteredResults = projects;

            filteredResults = projects.Where(x => x.code == selectedDistrictID);

            var pagedResults = filteredResults.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);
            var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, pagedResults, filteredResults.Count(), projects.Count()));

            return result;
        }
```

my controller is implementing Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
```

I found this question, but the answer didn't help me:

[CreateResponse method in asp.net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971390/createresponse-method-in-asp-net-web-api)

complete error is:

> Error 13  'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition
>   for 'CreateResponse' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,
>   System.Net.HttpStatusCode, T)' has some invalid arguments

do you see what I'm doing wrong? maybe something wrong with whats inside the `CreateResponse` method... thanks

Comment: This might help- https://forums.asp.net/t/2118105.aspx?Request+CreateResponse+not+found+What+is+the+alternative+

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have a feeling you're inheriting the wrong base controller type. If you're using WebAPI, you should inherit from `ApiController`, not `Controller`.

In `ApiController`, `Request` is `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`. In `Controller`, `Request` is `System.Web.HttpRequestBase`. So the extension method is close, but the incorrect types which is giving you the signature method mismatch.

Comment: I'm not using WebAPI.  The controller was using : Controller before, I just added a new method below that needed to return the HTTPResponse, so that is new to the class.

Comment: @user3461011 `CreateResponse` and `HttpResponseMessage` is supposed to be used from WebAPI. In your case, I'd either create a new WebAPI controller so you can use those members, or remove them and return a ViewResult of `Json` or similar so you can act like a API.

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: how to use HttpRequestMessage in asp.net core