# Parse Json object from Angular to C# ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a new Salesman with Angular and C#. From Angular i collect the data the user has typed into an array (newData) and sending it from my controller --> service to my C# controller server-side. But i get several errors and it can't get my object.

Angular controller:

```
$scope.addSalesman = function (newData) {
    myService.addNewSalesman(newData).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
```

Angular service:

```
addNewSalesman: function (newData) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/Salesman',
                headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
            }, newData).then(function (res) {
                deferred.resolve(res.data);
            }, function (res) {
                deferred.reject(res);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

C# controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] newData newdata) {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

My errors are on the C# controller:

> The type or namespace "newData" could not be found
>
> "HttpRequest" does not contain a definition for "CreateResponse"
>   accepting first argument of type "HttpRequest"

I tried adding the using **System.Net.Http;** and **using System.Net;** but doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting two compile time errors which don't really have anything to do with one another.

#### 1. The type or namespace "newData" could not be found

Is caused because your parameter type "newData" is not a known type in your code. Say you create a class like

```
public class Salesman
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the javascript object is

```
var salesman = {
    id = 2,
    name = "Peter Sellers"
};
```

Now when you're passing this object in, for example by using `$http.post`

```
var res = $http.post('/api/addsalesman', salesman);
res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(data);
});
res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error');
});
```

then the following Controller method would be able to parse it.

```
[Route("/api/addsalesman")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddSalesman([FromBody] Salesman salesman)
{

}
```

#### 2. "HttpRequest" does not contain a definition for "CreateResponse" accepting first argument of type "HttpRequest"

The method CreateResponse() doesn't exist for `this.Request`. Anyways, I would suggest returning an object, which would be automatically serialized. Alternatively, you could return a not found response resulting in 404, or even throw an Exception, resulting in Statuscode 500.

```
[Route("/api/addsalesman")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddSalesman([FromBody] Salesman salesman)
{
    //Do Stuff
    if (stuffNotOk)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(product); 
}
```

Comment: Very good explanation, but i'm getting an error with IHttpActionResult:

The type or namespace 'IHttpActionResult' could not be found. Not sure if i has anything to do with that i'm running ASP.NET Core Web Api. Just read a post where someone said, that i should use **using System.Net.Http;** but that doesn't do it.

Comment: What would the stuffNotOk be in my example to check on, if i may ask?

Comment: It would really depend on what you're doing with the Salesman object you received. Perhaps you wanna check if everything is valid before you store in a database or, when updating, if it exists in the first place.

Comment: Let's say if i want to check if it contains some data of any sort. How do i do that? Sorry for bothering you with these newbie questions

Comment: You could for example check if there's a name given with an if statement: `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(salesman.Name)){ ... }`
But this is really no longer on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have misspelled the name of the argument type you expect in your Post method:

```
//                                         v-- this is your sinner
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] newData newdata) {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Still the same error with both newData and CreateResponse :(

Comment: Do you have a class named `newData` in your C# project?

Comment: No, but i thought i just could parse the data fra Angular into it, so it knew what i was

Comment: C# is (generally) a strongly typed language. The method has to know which type the argument is. The place where you've put `newData` is actually where you tell C# which type to expect, so the compiler expects there to be a class named `newData`. You should replace that with the class you're actually expecting - if you don't have one yet, you should create one. Sigge explains it quite well in his answer so I suggest you look at that. I also suggest you to check out some tutorials on C#.

Comment: The JavaScript object "newData" that i'm parsing is at front-end side no problem getting it. Let's say it looks like this:

newData = {id: 1, name: 'Jannet'}

On the server side, i got my model to the Salesman:

public class Salesman {
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}

Should i then add a newData object further in my model class?

Comment: If the font-end type matches your `Salesman`-type, then server-side you should replace `newData` with `Salesman`.That's a start. But Sigge really have it all in his answer already. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The type or namespace "newData" could not be found

This means that class newData should be created which reflect data passed by UI

> "HttpRequest" does not contain a definition for "CreateResponse" accepting first argument of type "HttpRequest"

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971390/createresponse-method-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Since i'm working in an ASP.NET Core Web api project, i can't set the controllers extend to **ApiController**, but **Controller** instead (they merged it in the later versions, as i could read)